# isn't intel hd graphics supposed to have directx 11 feature level 11?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, gaming

I have `intel HD graphics` on my laptop, but every time I try t run a game (valorant and others), it keeps saying:

A D3D11 compatible GPU (feature level 11, shader mode 5.0) is required to run this engine.

According to  [Tech power up](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/hd-graphics.c2469) intel HD graphics have direct x 11 (feature level 11, shader mode 5.0). I ran `dxdiag` command, and my system shows I have DirectX 11, but the feature level is 10_1. isn't it supposed to have feature level 11 with me having intel HD graphics? or it's just my graphics card got some problems? could you please read the info below and give me a solution? I ran some Windows updates and downloaded DirectX 11 from the ms store (ig). what should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your issue is that Intel has not released a Windows 10 driver for their iGPU released back in 2011. This is supported by the fact the DirectX Diagnose report indicate WDDM is 1.2 instead of the most recent version on Windows 10.

Comment: The *interface* (DDI) is operating  as DirectX 11, as that's what the OS talks to the driver through,  but as stated in the answer by gronostaj your GPU (which is built into your CPU) only supports DirectX feature levels of 10.1 and below. That is a harware limitation that effectively locks you out of any and all DirectX 11 features.

Comment: so isn't there any way I could possibly fix this real quick?

Comment: @rei - How quickly can you drive down to Best Buy, Walmart, or Target and purchase newer harder?  The limitation is based off your hardware, unless you replace the hardware, your hardware is incompatible with the software you are trying to run.

Answer (score 1):

That's not your HD Graphics - there were multiple versions released under the same name. Your CPU was released in 2011, two years before that version of HD Graphics.

Comment: umm do you mean my CPU has to do something with the DirectX version? or my CPU doesn't support it that's why it doesn't have the feature level 11?

Comment: the iGPU is on the CPU die. A quick search of that model suggests shader 4.1

Comment: As Yorik said, HD Graphics is an integrated GPU. It means it's not a separate add-on card that you can install in a computer, but it's built into the CPU and the motherboard provides video outputs for it. At the time when your CPU was released that version of HD Graphics didn't exist yet.

Comment: I don’t think the above answers your Direct X version issue.  Are you running the systems I mentioned?  Direct X is also a software issue.

Comment: @John DirectX is software, but it needs hardware support. DirectX can operate at feature levels lower than installed as explained by Mokubai in his comment

Comment: You need proper software (OS) to run on the hardware. Only Windows 10 and 11 will provide DirectX 12 Support. No earlier OS will do this.

Comment: @John - What does DX12 have to do with the author’s problem, the author’s running Windows 10, they just have a processor from a decade ago likely on a machine that never was supposed to support Windows 10

Comment: I was just noting that (since the author is having issues with DX 11) that a modern machine with modern OS will run DX12 and solve the problem.  I would not waste time with old hardware and an old version of DX

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running Windows 10 and the latest Feature pack (19044.1949) or Windows 11 on a machine compatible with Windows 11 (and so Windows 10 as well)>

Direct X for those two above is DirectX12 and then that should probably solve your problem.

Make sure also that you have updated your Video Driver and Chipset.  Use the Manufacturer's Driver Update App to do these updates.

Making sure your hardware supports DX12 will be ideal for you.